# Problema subir archivos ajax y php

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

No sé que está ocurriendo pero no puedo subir archivos con php/ajax no me reconoce el index archivo, Mi código:

Html:

```
<div class="wrapper-attachment" data-type="attachment" style="display: none;">
  <form name='archivo' enctype="multipart/form-data" class='formulario'>
    <input type="file" class="hidden inputAttachment"/>
  </form>
  <div class="buttonAddAttach">
    <div class="img-wrapper buttonImage">
      <i class="icon-cloud-upload"></i>
    </div>
    <span class="buttonText">Subir archivo</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('change','.inputAttachment',function(e){
  var formData = new FormData($(this).parent()[0]);
  $.ajax({
    url: base_url + 'Task/upAttach',
    type: "POST",
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success:function(e){
      alert("exito");
      console.log(e);
    },
    error:function(e){
      alert("error");
      console.log(e);
    }
  });
});
```

PHP:

```
public function upAttach(){

  if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && 
     strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') 
  {

    //obtenemos el archivo a subir
    $file = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];

    //comprobamos si existe un directorio para subir el archivo
    //si no es así, lo creamos
    if(!is_dir("files/")) 
    mkdir("files/", 0777);

    //comprobamos si el archivo ha subido
    if ($file && move_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'],"files/".$file))
    {
      sleep(3);//retrasamos la petición 3 segundos
      echo $file;//devolvemos el nombre del archivo para pintar la imagen
    }
  }else{
    throw new Exception("Error Processing Request", 1);   
    echo ("error");
  }
}
```

Comment: ¿Aún no has encontrado una solución a tu problema? ¿Ninguna de las respuestas ha sido de ayuda? De lo contrario, considera marcar como aceptada la que ayudo solucionar tu problema y/o votar

Answer (score 0):

Si imprimes en consola de JavaScript el contenido de tu variable `formData` seguramente está vacía. Hasta donde recuerdo JQuery no incluye archivos en sus métodos ajax.

Estoy tomando el ejemplo de [aquí](https://abandon.ie/notebook/simple-file-uploads-using-jquery-ajax) y adaptándolo a tu caso; no olvides nombrar el input del archivo ya que en el código original no tiene nombre:

```js
var files;
$('input[type=file]').on('change', prepareUpload);
function prepareUpload(event){
 files = event.target.files;
}

$('form_archivo').on('submit', uploadFiles);

function uploadFiles(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  event.preventDefault();
  var data = new FormData();

$.each(files, function(key, value){
    data.append(key, value);
  });

  $.ajax({
    url: base_url + 'Task/upAttach',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
      if(typeof data.error === 'undefined'){
        submitForm(event, data);
      } else {
        console.log('ERRORS: ' + data.error);
      }
    }, error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
      console.log('ERRORS: ' + textStatus);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name='archivo' id="form_archivo" enctype="multipart/form-data" class='formulario'>
  <input type="text" name="texto" placeholder="escribe algún texto"><br />
  <input type="file" name="files" class="hidden inputAttachment"/><br />
  <input type="submit">
</form>
<br />
<div class="buttonAddAttach">
  <div class="img-wrapper buttonImage">
    <i class="icon-cloud-upload"></i>
  </div>
  <span class="buttonText">Subir archivo</span>
</div>
```

En tu código PHP puedes hacer inicialmente un `exit(var_dump($_FILES));` para saber que en realidad estás enviando archivos.

Answer (score 0):

Los errores en tu código son:

- El `<input type="file"` no tiene `name`.
- El `<form` tiene el nombre que deberia tener el `input`

### Solución:

Modificar tu `markup` de la siguiente forma:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" class='formulario'>
  <input name="archivo" type="file" class="hidden inputAttachment"/>
</form>
```